# gzip JSON payload before POST

Tags: json, go, gzip

I have a JSON object of type `[]byte` that I created from a struct using `json.Marshal`. I want to GZip the JSON before posting it to my endpoint. The following does not work:

```
gz := gzip.NewWriter(myJSON)
```

because `[]byte` does not implement `io.Writer`.

Is there some very simple way I can do this once I already have my JSON created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compress to a buffer and post that buffer.

```
 var buf bytes.Buffer
 gz := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
 gz.Write(myJSON)
 gz.Close()
```

Because a `*bytes.Buffer` statisifies the `io.Reader` interface, you can use the buffer directly when creating the request.

```
 req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, &buf)
 if err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
 req.Header.Set("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
 req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

Comment: Thank you! Are you doing something with 'bytesToPost := buf.Bytes()'? It seems you create it but then don't use it as you're passing &buf in the POST.

Comment: @JimmyD The line of code was intended to illustrate where the bytes to post are, but it looks like that didn't help.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

The best option is to stream your JSON marshaling to your gzip writer:

```
func compressJSON(w io.Writer, i interface{}) error {
    gz := gzip.NewWriter(w)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(gz).Encode(i); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return gz.Close()
}
```

This has the advantage of not buffering your json in memory temporarily, so it will be faster and use less RAM.

If you need this as an `io.Reader`, such as for the body of an HTTP request, you can use a pipe to do the conversion:

```
r, w := io.Pipe()
go func() {
    err := compressJSON(w, someObject)
    w.CloseWithError(err)
}()
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com/", r)
```